# Django Excel Export (using xlwt)

Tags: python, django, excel, export, xlwt

I'm trying to export data tied to an id from a view, to an excel file, this is the code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from clientesapp.models import Cliente, Orden
from django.http import HttpResponse
import xlwt

def excel_create(request, id):
    
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="recibo.xls"'

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('recibo')

    row_num = 0
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold=True

    columns = ['Orden', 'Cliente', 'Entrada', 'Instrumento', 'Marca',]

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()

    rows = Orden.objects.get(id=id)
    rows.values_list('num_orden', 'client', 'fechain', 'instrumento', 'marca')
    
    for row in rows:
        row_num +=1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)

    wb.save(response)

    return response
```

I want to export to excel this table, that also shows the id i need to get the data:
[Table with id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMZMI.png)

But this code shows me the error "Orden object have no attribute values_list".
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`QuerySet API`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) you have to call it like this:

```
rows = Orden.objects.values_list('num_orden', 'client', 'fechain', 'instrumento', 'marca', flat=True).get(pk=id)
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked, new problems popped up but i was able to solve them, thanks.

Comment: glad to help!..